# Confused. How to stop sound loop?

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to make an audio app which allows sound to be projected through the speaker via the mic. I made a toggle button for this app but after click on it, it stays highlighted and I can't adjust the system volume.
So how do i break this loop?

private void setUpButton() {

```
final ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tb);
tb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener (){

    public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
        if (on){
             boolean is = true;
             android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
             int buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(20000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
             AudioRecord arec = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 20000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize);
             AudioTrack atrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
             atrack.setPlaybackRate(20000);
             byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
             arec.startRecording();
             atrack.play();
             while(is) {
                 arec.read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
                 atrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
             }

}

    }});


}
```

Comment: This shouldn't run on the ui threat. Create a threat and run it there.

Comment: You are simply inside a loop that never ends. You should use other condition for reading the buffer, instead of using the always-true boolean `is`.

Comment: Can I have examples of other conditions to read it into? Sorry for the hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toggle button is staying highlighted because you have your infinite `while(is){...}` loop running in the main UI thread (as per 323go's comment). The main UI thread becomes busy constantly running the infinite loop and therefore does not have the opportunity to process any more UI actions such as further button state updates etc.

Move your infinite loop into it's own thread with a message handler to handle messages from your main UI thread telling it when to start or stop etc. This will free up the main UI thread to do what it's meant to be doing ... handling the User Interface.
For example:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity {

    private AudioScheduler mAudioThread;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAudioThread = new AudioThread();
        mAudioThread.start();

        final ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tb);
        tb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener (){

            public void onClick(View view) {
            Message messageToAudioThread = Message.obtain();
            boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
            if (on){
                messageToAudioThread.what = AudioThread.PLAY;
            } else {
                messageToAudioThread.what = AudioThread.STOP;
            }
            mAudioThread.getHandler().sendMessage(messageToAudioThread);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {        
        super.onDestroy();
        mAudioThread.close();
    }
}
```

**AudioThread**

```
public class AudioThread extends Thread {

    // Handler message constants
    public static final int PLAY = 0;
    public static final int STOP = 1;

    // Class variables
    private boolean mRunning = false;
    private boolean mPlayAudio = false;

    private static class AudioThreadHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<AudioThread> mThread;

        public AudioThreadHandler(AudioThread thread) {
            mThread = new WeakReference<AudioThread>(thread);
        }

        @Override
        public  void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            AudioThread thread = mThread.get();
            if (thread != null) {
                switch(msg.what) {
                case PLAY:
                    thread.mPlayAudio = true;
                    break;
                case STOP:
                    thread.mPlayAudio = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private final AudioThreadHandler mAudioThreadHandler = new AudioThreadHandler(this);

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            mRunning = true;            
            while(mRunning) {
                if (mPlayAudio) {
                    // Your code for handling audio recording/playback
                    // or whatever goes here
                } else {
                    // If you have code you want to keep executing while
                    // audio is not active, stick it here
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("AudioThread", "Thread Loop Exception: " + e);
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        mRunning = false;
    }

    public Handler getHandler() {
        return mAudioThreadHandler;
    }
}
```

From your description you are wanting to record, manipulate (adjust volume etc), and output audio all in real time. For that level of audio processing you will need to understand and use threads. There are plenty of good examples and tutorials out there if you don't already have a good grasp of threads.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll read up more on it if this doesn't help!

Comment: You're welcome. BTW I found this [3 part tutorial on Android Threads](http://indyvision.net/2010/01/android-threads-tutorial/) really helpful myself. PS: Remember to accept answers to your questions if they are helpful.

Comment: Hi, I used the example you gave and it worked great. But, I can't seem to stop the recording and playback at all. Is it because I included a while loop as it is needed for it to constantly read and playback.

Comment: The `while(mRunning) {...}` loop in my example code acts as the infinite loop where you should do your `arec.read` and `atrack.write`. Do not nest them inside a further infinite loop, if that's what you've done.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I do assume I put the codes I needed for recording and playback in if (mPlayAudio) {...} right? If so, I only receive sound for only a brief moment. Please do correct me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: Correct, but remember that the code you put there is going to be constantly looped through. That means if you have `arec.startRecording()` and `atrack.play()` in there, they will constantly keep re-starting on each pass through the loop. To overcome this you'll need to put them in conditional statments so they only start if they're not already going. For example `if(arec.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED) {arec.startRecording()}`

Comment: Also you only want to instantiate your objects once, so you should create your objects such as arec, atrack, buffersize and buffer before you enter the while loop. I'd do that inside the try/catch block where I've assigned `mRunning = true`.

Comment: Oh, and of course you'll want to stop your streams in the `else` section of the `if (mPlayAudio)` block, which executes when mPlayAudio is false.

Comment: Finally got it. Thank you for your time and patience!